# After jenkins build complete downloading a file from build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my case after build completes zip file will be created .Is there any way to provide a direct link inside build (For ex : at left side where we see 'Console Output' in that location) so that on click it takes to download location or downloads directly.(So that user need not to go to location and download explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

You can archive your zip file firstly.

Then you get it either inside the build page or from the last successful build page which is in the main job page.

https://xxxx/job/hello/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/